# Passing PHP Session Value

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I'm attempting to pass a value from one WordPress page to another through a PHP Session. I have a dropdown list on both pages, which are identical except for the option values. I would like the selected option on the 2nd page at page load to reflect the chosen value submitted on the first page.

I've looked into a lot of questions but haven't been able to find exactly what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Page 1:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
        session_start(); 
        echo $_SESSION['state'];
        $var_value = $_SESSION['state'];
    } 
?>

<form>
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="page2.php">
    <select id="state" name="state">
        <option>State 1</option>
        <option>State 2</option>
        <option>State 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['state'])){
        $_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];
    }
?>

<select>
    <option <?php if($var_value == 'State 1') echo 'selected'; ?> value="http://customizedlink">State 1</option>
    <option <?php if($var_value == 'State 2') echo 'selected'; ?> value="http://customizedlink">State 2</option>
    <option <?php if($var_value == 'State 3') echo 'selected'; ?> value="http://customizedlink">State 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is the code to be run on posting of first page ?

Comment: _"the chosen value submitted on the first page"_ - submitted _where to_? Since your code you have shown for "page 2" simply reads the value from $_POST, I assume "page 2" is where you are sending the data to in the first place? If so, what makes you think this would need sessions ...? You _already have_ access to the values via $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

> WordPress core does not use PHP sessions. The WordPress platform is totally stateless and provides no support
>   for the use of sessions outside of the cookie that keeps a user logged
>   in.

WordPress core does not use PHP sessions, but sometimes they are required by your use-case, a plugin or theme.

You can use [WordPress Native PHP Sessions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-php-sessions/) plugin that implements PHP’s native session handlers, backed by the WordPress database.

see [Using the PHP Session in WordPress](https://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to tell us how you're getting from Page 1 to Page 2.  But, let's assume that when you `SELECT` in Page 1, Page 1 is called again.  In that case, you need to move your `$_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];` assignment from Page 2 to Page 1.  It **must** occur **before** you move to Page 2.

Also, Page 2 is using something called `$var_value` which isn't set anywhere in your examples.  Did you mean to execute `$var_value = $_SESSION['state'];` somewhere above the `SELECT` in Page 2?

If none of this leads you to an answer, please provide more information about the context of your code.

---

Try this.  Your Page 1 `FORM` element, when submitted, calls Page 1.  Therefore...

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
        session_start(); 
        if( isset($_POST['state']) ){
            $_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];
        }
        echo "Page 1: ".$_SESSION['state'];
    } 
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="page2.php">
    <select id="state" name="state">
        <option>State 1</option>
        <option>State 2</option>
        <option>State 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Page 2

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "Page 2: ".$_SESSION['state'];
    $var_value = $_SESSION['state'];
?>

<select>
    <option <?php if($var_value == 'State 1') echo 'selected'; ?> value="http://customizedlink">State 1</option>
    <option <?php if($var_value == 'State 2') echo 'selected'; ?> value="http://customizedlink">State 2</option>
    <option <?php if($var_value == 'State 3') echo 'selected'; ?> value="http://customizedlink">State 3</option>
</select>
```

You should see the correct value for `$_SESSION['state']` in Page 2 (after running Page 1) **IF** I have understood the intent of your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for not being clear. The purpose of the $var_value is to create a variable for the value of the selected field from Page 1. I want the browser to remember the Page 1 value while on Page 2, and use it to determine which of the fields should be marked as selected.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but you cannot set it in Page 1 and expect it to be available in Page 2.  Don't use it.  Use `$_SESSION['state']` directly.

Comment: Great explanation and it looks like you understand what I am looking to accomplish. My issue now is that I am receiving "Undefined Index" warnings on both pages, so I haven't been able to appropriately test this solution.

Comment: Can you debug this on your own?  If not, let me know which index is undefined.

Comment: It's instances of the index "state"...on Page 1, Line 7 of your code. Lines 3 & 4 on Page 2. Not sure why that would be a problem since the select field is properly named.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151933/discussion-between-usefulbattery-and-jbh).