# Restrict access to page based on referrer page

Tags: php, wordpress, security, authentication

I need to restrict access to a page only if visitor came from specific wordpress page(s).

I have been Reading here since morning and most answers I see discourage the use of "just" referrer because it can be spoof.

I do not know much about php security and vulnerabilities. My only aim is to "discourage" users bookmarking the page and access to it directly. I need to validate visitors on our wordpress website and point them to the page only when they are authenticated.

Currently what I came up so far is this.

```
<?php

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$theOrigins = array(
'http://mysite.tld/?page_id=x1',
'http://mysite.tld/?page_id=x2');

$validRef = false;

if (in_array($ref, $theOrigins)) {
$validRef = true;
}


if (isset($_GET['passkey']) && ($_GET['passkey'] == 'thePasskey') &&  $validRef ) {
?>

<show html page>

<?php
} else {
//echo 'You are not supposed to access this page directly';
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
exit('Forbidden');
}
?>
```

This is mostly based on the answer in this post

[What is the best way to password protect folder/page using php without a db or username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286938/what-is-the-best-way-to-password-protect-folder-page-using-php-without-a-db-or-u)

I am planning to add the solution in this page

http://thisinterestsme.com/restricting-access-referrer/

But according to this post,

[Passing PHP Session Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680649/passing-php-session-value)

wp does not use sessions

Is this instruction on how to use wp session no longer applicable in current wp versions?

https://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look wrong to me. What happens if you brows to your site?

Comment: Why not set a session when they are authenticated and check that instead of checking referrer? The referrer header isn't always set, since some routers clears it for privacy reasons. If someone has such a router, they will never be able to access the page.

Comment: @MatthiasMoritz there is nothing wrong but most answers I see here discourage referrer as form of authentication because it can be spoof.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that was the plan but one of the link I provided said wp has no session. I quote from the post "WordPress core does not use PHP sessions. The WordPress platform is totally stateless and provides no support for the use of sessions outside of the cookie that keeps a user logged in."

Comment: What Wordpress uses is irrelevant. You can hook into WP's authentication and set your own session.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you mean the solution on https://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/ can still work on current wordpress?

Comment: Didn't read the full article but yes, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Moin,

if you know that what you are trying to do is insecure (possibility to manipulate the HTTP header HTTP_REFERER), you could try to be less specific about the allowed URLs. Maybe just check for the right host:

```
if(strpos($ref, 'mysite.tld') !== false && $_GET['passkey'] == 'thePasskey')
{ ... }
```

Comment: The OP is already checking the full URL (including the hostname _and_ query string) so I'm not getting why this (which only checks the hostname) would be more secure?

Comment: The goal of this suggestion is not to be more secure. 
The goal is to validate the referer without the GET parameters.
The in_array condition of the first if of the posted code does not consider the GET parameter 'passkey', so the second if will never be true.
Therefore its best to be less specific at validating the referer URL